# Show only Browser version

Tags: javascript

On Stackoverflow i have found a piece of code which shows me my Browser version:

```
 navigator.sayswho= (function(){
  var N= navigator.appName, ua= navigator.userAgent, tem;
  var M= ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie)\/?\s*(\.?\d+(\.\d+)*)/i);
  if(M && (tem= ua.match(/version\/([\.\d]+)/i))!= null) M[2]= tem[1];
  M= M? [M[1], M[2]]: [N, navigator.appVersion,'-?'];
  return M;
 })();
```

This is giving me the folowing output:

IE: MSIE10.0

Chrome: Chrome26.0.1410.64

FireFox: Firefox19.0

Opera: Opera12.12

Safari: Safari5.1.7

I was wondering if it is possible with this function to show only the version numbers so without Chrome, FireFox etc. So only: 26.0.1410.64 etc.

Comment: Have you googled "javascript browser version"?

Answer (score 2):

That function already returns the browser name and version separately in an array. Use `navigator.sayswho[1]` to get the version only.

Comment: Your code works as is. Just use `navigator.sayswho[1]` when you need the version.